# Calculating Fridays on 13th between two dates separated by a space

Tags: java, date

```
Date startdate=new Date();
Date enddate=new Date();
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy",Locale.US);


Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);    
String line = scanner.nextLine();
String line1 = scanner.nextLine();

try{
    startdate = format.parse(line);
} 
 catch(ParseException e){
    System.out.println("Sorry!!");
}

try {
    enddate = format.parse(line1);
} 
catch(ParseException e){
    System.out.println("Sorry!!");
}
```

Well my code works correctly if my dates are given on two separate lines. But I want to make it work for input in the same line separated by space (between two dates as well as between the day month year (DD MM YYYY format for each date)).

Input is like: 01 01 2015 10 10 2015

I need to scan these two dates in startdate and enddate respectively. How can I do it?

Comment: Hmm your question is more about splitting strings than calculation of days so I'd adjust that. As for your problem: split the string and then pass each part to the date format for parsing. Splitting can be done by using `substring` if you know the length or by regex if you know only the format to look for.

Comment: Your program shows no sign of "Friday on 13th", but it does require the input to be on **two lines** (two calls to `nextLine()`), and `01 01 2015 10 10 2015` is a single line of text.

Comment: Thanks everyone!! I have it solved now!! Sorry I can't +1 because of my rep :(

Answer (score 1):

You could use `substring`

```
  String Str = new String("01 01 2015 10 10 2015");

  System.out.println(Str.substring(11) );   // 10 10 2015

  System.out.println(Str.substring(0, 10) );  // 01 01 2015
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a guideline on how you should do this. I expect you to write your own code.

- Take the input to a string. (one line with both dates)
- Split the string on the space in the middle.
- And then feed each part to the `format.parse();`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the exact length of the string, i.e. one could pass Jan 1st 2015 as `1 1 2015` as well or other characters in between (e.g. multiple spaces), try using a regular expression:

```
String input = "1 1 2015   10 10 2015";

SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile( "[0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{1,2} [0-9]{4}" );
Matcher m = p.matcher( input );

while( m.find() )
{
  System.out.println( f.parse( m.group() ) );
}
```

Short breakdown of the expression:

- `[0-9]{1,2}` means one or two ascii digits (`\d` would match non-ascii digits as well)
- `[0-9]{4}` means exactly four ascii digits
- The digit groups are separated by a single space, i.e. they match the rough pattern `x y z` and any input with more than one space in between wouldn't match.

Answer (score 0):

Well, direct 1 on 1 to your code. This how you should do it.

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);    
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1,2}\\s+[0-9]{1,2}\\s+[0-9]{4}");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(line);

    String d1 = null;
    String d2 = null;

    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy",Locale.US);

    Date startDate = null;
    Date endDate = null;

    try {
        if(m.find()) {
            d1 = m.group();
            startDate = format.parse(d1);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry for date 1.");
        }
        if(m.find()) {
            d2 = m.group();
            endDate = format.parse(d2);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Sorry for date 2.");
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Incorrect date format");
    }
```